# Ubuntu SSH EC2 Broken Pipe after adding Elastic IP to Instance

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

Working with AWS EC2, I had a working m5.large instance running Ubuntu 16 with a regular IP address. I added limited access sftp users by editing /etc/sshd/config to the machine, which worked fine. Then, I added an Elastic IP address to the box and now I get a broken pipe error whenever I attempt to access the box. I tried replicating the issue by launching an identical instance via AMI snapshot and attempted to purge openssh and reinstall it via the userdata box, but the second instance also gets the same error. The web server works fine, I just can't access it from any machine. It appears to login fine via the private/public key pair but the last step ends all connection. Instance id is i-03bdf244d7b1c98e6 and the copy I created is i-04f02a5ec0c209a44.

This is the verbose output I get:

```
ssh ubuntu@34.225.96.92 -i ~/.ssh/xxxxxxx.pem -vvv
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/xxxxxxxx/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 34.225.96.92 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 34.225.96.92 [34.225.96.92] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxx.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxx.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.7 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 34.225.96.92:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:66
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 34.225.96.92
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ojf1ko9ntOaWR59QrGDg04Ft7uGLCiK7fSks7D91NUY
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:66
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 34.225.96.92
debug1: Host '34.225.96.92' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/amatusko/.ssh/known_hosts:66
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxx.pem RSA SHA256:US/RaCxmNUMq224OF+MQ4g5Swdh4YEnU3v3mX9WRcPU agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/blogsftp RSA SHA256:lzv9cpAmHg8GOZBZ4CR7GsuikzEXC3WzjuQbi6Sp+jA agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxx  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxx.pem RSA SHA256:US/RaCxmNUMq224OF+MQ4g5Swdh4YEnU3v3mX9WRcPU agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxx.pem RSA SHA256:US/RaCxmNUMq224OF+MQ4g5Swdh4YEnU3v3mX9WRcPU agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:US/RaCxmNUMq224OF+MQ4g5Swdh4YEnU3v3mX9WRcPU
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 34.225.96.92 ([34.225.96.92]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to 34.225.96.92 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Any ideas on how to rectify this? The box is kind of useless without ssh.